# Using change function with that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to make a simple function to try **change function** but it didn't go as I expected:/

What I am trying to do:
1- as a cost checkboxe is checked, assign the cost like(cost1.checked ? cost1 = 10 : 0)
2- as a checkbox is checked give a result with sum of the checkbox costs.

Problem I get : [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3zbm/

this is my code:

```
$('#cost1').click(function(){
if(this.checked){
var cost1 = 10;
}else{
cost1 = 0;
}
});
$('#cost2').click(function(){
if(this.checked){
var cost2 = 20;
}else{
cost2 = 0;
}
});
$('#cost3').click(function(){
if(this.checked){
var cost3 = 30;
}else{
cost3 = 0;
}
});
$('.costs').change(function(){
var result = cost1 + cost2 + cost3;
$('.total').text(result);
});
```

I know it's too simple:s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare your variables out of your functions, and try to use a function for recalculation (to be sure that it's called when you want).

```
var cost1 = 0;
var cost2 = 0;
var cost3 = 0;
function recalculate()  {
    var result = cost1 + cost2 + cost3;
    $('.total').text(result);
}
$('#cost1').click(function(){
    cost1 = this.checked ? 10 : 0;
    recalculate();

});
$('#cost2').click(function(){
    cost2 = this.checked ? 20 : 0;
    recalculate();
});
$('#cost3').click(function(){
    cost3 = this.checked ? 30 : 0;
    recalculate();
});
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3zbm/1/)

Comment: Thanx! so my variables were private? is that it?

Comment: not really private, but they were not in the scope of the last function (the last function didn't know about int variables cost1, cost2, cost3, which where only known in each click functions)...

Answer (score 1):

In your code you were actually selecting the checkbox html elements, with this working code, it will accomplish your task::

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/L5RYm/

```
var result=0;
$('.costs').change(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            result=result+parseInt($(this).val());
        }else{
            result=result-parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('.total').text(result);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can be also, indeed thnx!